# Developing an ILIAS plugin

Tags: ilias

For an assignment I have to develop a plugin to stream a video in ilias, getting it from a different website. Is there an easy plugin with some basic things that all plugins need? Like a 'Hello world' plugin for ilias. Also any other tips for ILIAS is welcome.

I have a working ILIAS setup running and am able to install/update/activate existing plugins.

Answer (score 2):

The best place to start writing plugins for ILIAS is to check out [ilias.de->Development->Development Guide->Plugins](http://www.ilias.de/docu/goto_docu_pg_27030_42.html).

Depending on what exactly you try to accomplish you need a different plugin type. If you would like to insert videos in any page element such as the page editor or the wiki, you probably want to create a **Page Component Plugin**. If you would like to use it as a kind of module (such as files, folders, tests, etc.) that can be added by clicking "Add new Item", you would need to do a **Repository Object Plugin**.

In my opinion, creating a **Repository Object Plugin** is the best way to start writting plugins for ILIAS. Like that you learn the basics of permissions, modules and control flow.

A "Hello World" example of a **Repository Object Plugin** can be found in the according section at the very bottom ("Example").

You can find many other examples in the [plugin database](http://www.ilias.de/docu/goto_docu_dcl_3342.html) of ilias.de

Comment: I'm going for a repository object plugin. I think that dummy plugin might be    quite usefull. Thank you for the tip!

Comment: Do you know of any Youtube like plugins for ILIAS maybe? that is exactly what I need to make, but thn for a differend media.

Comment: Do you mean a central repository for storing and sharing clips? I am sure you find something that shares common items among users in the plugin database (see my answer above).

Comment: something that can show clips, stored on a central server, or serveres. It has to give the teacher he possibility to choose the query's.

Comment: A plugin I know that has maybe some functionality you describe is the [Switch-Cast](https://github.com/studer-raimann/Scast/releases) plugin. To make it work you need a central server though, managing the videos. Searching for videos is not really possible. You can only access the videos you own.